# How To Create File System Fragmentation?

Tags: windows-xp, fragmentation

Risk Factors for File Fragmentation include mostly full Disks and repeated file appends.  What are other risk factors for file fragmentation?  How would one make a program using common languages like C++/C#/VB/VB.NET to work with files & make new files with the goal of increasing file fragmentation?

WinXP / NTFS is the target

Edit: Would something like this be a good approach?  Hard Drive free space = FreeMB_atStart

- Would creating files of say 10MB to fill
  90% of the remaining hard drive space
- Deleting every 3rd created file
- making file of size FreeMB_atStart * .92 / 3

Comment: Why would you want to increase file fragmentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should achieve at least some level of fragmentation on most file systems:

1. Write numerous small files,
2. Delete some at random files,
3. Writing a large file, byte-by-byte.

Writing it byte-by-byte is important, because otherwise if the file system is intelligent, it can just write the large file to a single contiguous place.

Comment: So out using C++ and fstream be recommended for control? To write byte-by-byte, would you just use a outputFile.flush after each byte?

Comment: Well, it would be much easier if you didn't use a buffered output stream in the first place. What about using putch()?

Comment: Still won't help. Too many operating systems just won't bother. Also, you can write 512 bytes at a time. No OS uses a smaller allocation unit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to write several files simultaneously byte-by-byte. This would probably have more effect.